# Why do I get syntax error from VueSourceSnippet.js when creating a Cube.js Dashboard App?

Tags: cube.js

I have followed the steps here https://cube.dev/docs/getting-started to create the project scaffolding and then have started the dev server from the project directory with

```
$npm run dev
```

Now, within the developer application being served at http://localhost:4000/#/template-gallery I click Create App for any of the templates.

I then get the following error everytime, show in my browser and in the terminal

```
err /home/mat/git/load-cube/node_modules/.tmp/cubejs-playground-templates-master/packages/templates-core/src/VueSourceSnippet.js:8
  scriptSource = null;
               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
/home/mat/git/load-cube/node_modules/.tmp/cubejs-playground-templates-master/packages/templates-core/src/VueSourceSnippet.js:8
  scriptSource = null;
               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

I am using Ubuntu v18.04; node v10.15.2

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for instance class fields starts with node >= 12. Anyway, it's been fixed and should work on node 10 as well.

P.S. node 10 is about 3 years old and they're dropping support this April https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/